# Reading data from files from a user input

Tags: python, file, text

So I have a text file that I've made up with a persons name followed by a comma and then a place where they could live. Yes I know its random but I need a way to understand this :)

So here is the text file (called "namesAndPlaces.txt"):

Bob,Bangkok
Ellie,London
Anthony,Beijing
Michael,Boston
Fred,Texas
Alisha,California

So I want the user to be able to enter a name into the program and then the program looks at the text file to see where they live and then prints it out to the user.

How can I do this? 
Thanks
Michael

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: search file for a string and print the full line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942691/python-search-file-for-a-string-and-print-the-full-line)

Comment: Can you show your code for this? Indicate what problems you are experiencing. Show any error messages you have received in your latest attempt. Also please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
text_file = open('pathtoFile', 'r').read()
text = text_file.split()

#turn the text into a dictionary
names_dic = []
for x in text:
    x = x.split(',')
    names_dic.append(x)

names_dic = dict(names_dic)

print names_dic  #for testing

# asking a user to enter a name
name = "not_in_dic"
while name not in names_dic:
    name = raw_input("Enter the name? ")
    print name, "lives in ", names_dic[name]
```

Comment: You can also add if statement, if name not in name_dic print " name was not found"

Answer (score 0):

A bit more pythonic way of doing the same thing Aneta suggested

```
with open(filename, 'r') as source:
    text = source.read()
    place_to_names = dict([line.split(r',') for line in text.split()])

while True:
    name = raw_input('Enter a name:')
    print("%s lives in %s" % (name, places_to_names[name]))
```